# How to set production environment for rails app being deployed with capistrano and passenger

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capistrano

Can't seem to find anything definitive here. When I 'cap deploy' my app, I am getting my files pushed over OK. However, the db is not being migrated. If I manually go to /myapp/current and run 'rake db:migrate' (should I have to do this?) the it creates db/development.sqlite which leads me to beleive my environment is set to dev. I have tried setting both set :deploy_env, "production" and set :rails_env, "production" in my delopy.rb file with no change. Any help appreciated.

PS
Would be nice if I could add the migration as a part of the deploy, rather than have to manually do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `cap db:migrate` in order to run your migrations with Capistrano. As far as the environment is concerned, [Multistage Extension](https://github.com/capistrano/capistrano/wiki/2.x-Multistage-Extension) could be really helpful.

Comment: You were close...correct command was cap deploy:migrations. I fixed your answer and gave you credit. Thanx!

Answer (score 2):

Assuming capistrano 2.x try `cap deploy:migrations` to deploy and migrate the database.
You can also use `cap deploy:migrate` to run migrations in recently deployed application.
Take a look at capistrano wiki for more details: https://github.com/capistrano/capistrano/wiki/Capistrano-Tasks

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are missing `require 'capistrano/rails/migrations'` in your Capfile?